# C# "Command-Line arguments exception"

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

How can I store a string command line argument in to a self defined string variable. As it tend to give "Array Index out of Range Bounds"...

Here is the code,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Prac1_e
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a String and a number : ");
            Console.Read();
            string str = args[0];
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the input string that you have typed in

Comment: are you passing an argument to the application?

Comment: You are reading `arg` which has value when you execute your program with arguments in command line. When you want run-time arguments, you have to read from `Console.Read();` itself. It has a return type of string.

Comment: @praty good catch. Modified my answer to include both options.

Comment: @praty " It has a return type of string" sorry, but no, it has a return type of int and it reads only the next character from the input stream. May be you meant `ReadLine` ?=!

Comment: @MongZhu, yup sorry.. my bad :). I meant `ReadLine()` which is also what I have used in my answer!

Comment: You should consider to use this lib to parse arguments, very useful and no ex like this: https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommandLineParser/

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to access the first two command line argument (`agrs[0]` and `args[1]`), but aren't passing any. Just pass some arguments and you should be fine:

```
Program somearg anotherarg
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments need to be passed via the command line in the format `appname.exe "arg1" "arg2"` etc. Also, since you are converting to an `Int`, you may want to validate that `arg[1]` is convertible to an `Int`.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a String and a number : ");
        Console.Read();
        if(args.Length >= 2)
        {
            string str = args[0];
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(args[1]);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Args passed");
        }
    }
```

If you are looking to capture runtime parameters via command-line, you would need to do something like the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a String and a number, with a space between: ");
        string consoleRead = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] parsed = consoleRead.Split(' ');
        if (parsed.Length > 1)
        {
            string str = parsed[0];
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(parsed [1]);
            Console.WriteLine(str);
            Console.WriteLine(n);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to read arguments passed in run-time from command line, you would need to read from `Console` object. You can try this code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a String and a number : ");

        string str = Console.ReadLine();
        int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        Console.WriteLine(n);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I would let @KamleshSharma confirm if this is what he wanted to achieve or if he really wanted to read a command line argument.

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope this is more descriptive than before.

Comment: definetely, it increases the quality of your answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

No error in this code. But you will get above error, when you execute the program incorrectly.
this should be the correct way:

```
[program name] [argument 1] [argument 2]
```

ex:

```
testprogram arg1 5
```